# Grouped Bar Chart in R using GoogleVis

Tags: r, googlevis

I am trying to create Grouped bar chart similar to the below attached image with 2 Dimensions and one measure.
[Grouped Bar Chart]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUQ5Y.png

I can achieve this using ggplot2 package, but the charts created using ggplot are not interactive like when I place cursor on a bar it wont show the tooltips. So I am preferring ggplot2 here.

How can I create chart similar to the attached image using googleVis package?

Comment: Hey Bhargavi Gali, in order to get help you need to provide a bit more information and best also a piece of reproducible code. For R you find information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We used plotly package for achieving interactive visualizations instead of google visualizations which satisfied our requirement of Grouped bar chart .